# What is the proper way to wait a script loaded completely before another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a website that is divided by several sections

```
<div id='section-1' class='section'>web content</div>
<div id='section-2' class='section'>web content</div>
```

I have like ten sections on my webpage ,each sections height is set to the user window height when document is ready by javascript

```
$('.section').height($(window).height());
```

Some effects like slideshows on my webpage require the calculated height of the section in order to work properly. Therefore I always use something like this at document ready as a solution.

```
setTimeout(startslideshow,1000);
setTimeout(startanimations,1000); ...etc
```

To make sure the section height is the user window height before the slideshow's code start because the sections cannot change to user window height instantly once the webpage loaded will generate serious problems in my slideshow code,like wrong calculated positions.

Therefore there will be a situation that's after the page loaded, there will be about a second everything is messed up,before everything can works properly, how could I avoid that being seen by the user? I tried to `$(document).hide()`,or `$('html,body').hide()`, then fade in after a second,but I get other weird problems, especially on ipad,my fixed position top navigation bar will always become 'not fixed' while user is scrolling.

As I am a self-learner, I afraid my method is not typical.
I want to know what is the common ways of real web programmers usually do when they have to divide his webpage into different sections and set its height to window height , then make sure the other effects that's depends on the section height works properly and avoid to wait the height change for a second?

Comment: Why not just call `startslideshow` and `startanimations` manually once you've finished those calculations?

Comment: I have a lot of different effects , divided into many many different js script files and linked them all in the header, that'd be extremely long if I put them all in the same file.Also how would I know it has really finished its caculations???I am just estimate it to be 1 second

Comment: Maybe the calculation function need to provide a callback function, which will be called after it finishes.

Comment: Yes, as @djakapm said, you asked what the proper way to do it would be, and this is it- to refactor your code to either call callbacks, or to be a part of a larger routine that calls each one in turn. Otherwise, how do you expect to keep track of them? There's nothing that can magically do it. You don't have to put them all in the same file, either, you can call functions defined in other files.

Comment: uhm, height() didn't provide call back function, but it actually do take times to finish it's operation as I saw it on browser,especially for a not very fast one,you can see it loading changing it's height obviously,if my code run at that moment, there are problems,I do really encountered them.Some codes doesn't works if I take away the timeout function.

Comment: You can call functions at other js files? I think all variable and functions only can be called in its own, otherwise it will be a mess? I use many same variable and function names but different purposes at different files

Comment: There's this plugin that helps you react when elements change size, position, etc: http://www.jqui.net/demo/mutate/ it may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [chaining Asynchronous calls.](http://lennybacon.com/post/2011/10/03/chainingasynchronousjavascriptcalls)

relying on timers is not recommended as scripts may execute at different speeds on different browsers, hardware, etc.

Comment: oh my god , that's too complicated, I think I will just keep my timer ... I tested on different browsers, I think normally browser will finished the height() changes in 500-800ms, if I put 1000ms delay b4 my script start,  it should be safe, but just a bit mess before 1 second, I am thinking of make a new div to cover the mess at that second or hide the elements, but if I make a new div to cover elements still blink out at that second,I'm still thinking....

Comment: The problem with that is that you can do all the testing in the world and you might not run into the odd case where the browser has some sort of hiccup that results in a delay that throws all of your timing off..

You can use calls as a previous commenter suggested. Just wrap your functionallity into a jQuery plugin to add callbacks to those functions that don't have already..

Comment: what is callback();? do I need to add callback(); at the end of all my functions?

Comment: A callback is a function that you pass into a process and expect to have it called when a condition is met. e.g. "operation succeeded". In your case, you need a function to be called when your height() change is complete. Take a look at the link I posted as a comment to the main question.

Comment: oh I just nearly get it, it means putting another function into the function like function a (callbacks){//something; callbacks()}; function b(){ //something} then substitute function b into a to make sure b is the later one. function a( function(){b()});  , awww headache

Comment: If programming is giving you headaches, then it may be time for a popsicle :)